# Solve the following system of equations modulo.

Tags: number-theory

[image]

Is 2 a) answer is (101)(mod 234) ?

and b) answer is (148)(mod 216) ?

Comment: or a) 153(mod234) b) 110(mod 216)

Comment: If you have candidate answer what stops you from dividing it  by 13 and 18 and get remainders. If the remainders are as expected in the question the answer is correct. Why do you need this forum for doing this verification?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Try to apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

It will work perfectly since $13$ and $18$ are relatively primes, and so does $8$ and $27$.